# lluminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found

Tags: state.go

lluminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'return_purchases.purchase_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select sum(`return_purchases`.`grand_total`) as aggregate from `purchases` inner join `return_purchases` on `purchases`.`id` = `return_purchases`.`purchase_id` where (`purchases`.`supplier_id` = 2 and `purchases`.`payment_status` = 1)) (View: /home/vol17_2/ultihost.net/ufhne_34544053/htdocs/resources/views/backend/supplier/index.blade.php)

fix the problem please